# Visual Studio 2010 , QT and intellisense/highlight error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, qt5

Hi have a problem with VisualStudio 2010 and the QT5 plugin, it seems that VisualStudio doesnt recognize the QT Library (despite i have installed the plugin and followed the whole procedure).

This is what I see:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/yyzvfev0zoj8x9n/visualstrudel.jpg

So the IDE highlights the QT stuff like if the files were not present, and Intellisense is not working. But, If I compile the application, it compiles without error and works like a charm.

What could be the cause of  the highlight/Intellisense issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot launch Visual Studio 2010 directly.

You will need to launch the QT 5.0.1 for Desktop(MSVC 2010) command line from Program Files->Qt 5.0.1->5.0.1

After which you will need to run the vcvarsall.bat and devenv after.

```
x:\program files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0.\VC\vcvarsall.bat
x:\program files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0.\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
```

Answer (score 2):

This is applicable to **VS2012** and **Qt4.5.0**, though I believe Qt version does not matter.
I am not sure if it is the same/similar to VS2010, but I stumbled upon this post while looking the answer to the same question for VS2012.

Here is what you can do:

1. Right-click the project in your solution and select **Properties**.
2. Select **Configuration Properties** -> **VC++ Directories**.
3. Edit **Include Directories** entry.
4. Add **$(QTDIR)\include\QtCore** and any other (required by your project) Qt folders to the list (it depends what Qt headers you are using).
5. This has to be done to every project in your solution that uses Qt, unfortunately.

Now, there is another note:
We were transferring our solution from VS2005 to VS2012 and that problem happened to me when I converted the solution 2005->2012 **BEFORE** setting the **QTDIR** environment variable.
When I re-converted the solution again (**AFTER** **QTDIR** variable was created) the problem didn't appear. So make sure you have this variable before you open/convert your solution for the first time.

Based on the previous note, I believe that some information related to the issue is stored in one of the following files: **.sdf** and/or **.v11.suo**.
So closing VS, deleting these files and opening VS again might help. Just back them up before you do it - I haven't tried it myself (I just re-imported the whole solution which generated these files anew).